# Tracking Survey Monkey responses in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, surveymonkey

I am building a rails application that requires users to take a survey on Survey Monkey. How can I reliably correlate a user of my app to their Survey Monkey response, which I am pulling using the Survey Monkey API? Matching IP would work some of the time, but its not very reliable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the 'custom id' (aka 'custom value') when sending the survey:

http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Can-I-track-respondents-using-a-unique-ID

You can also do this with email collectors as long as you fill out the recipient correct and populate its custom value.

Then when you call [get_respondent_list](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_respondent_list) ask for 'custom_id' as one of the fields, this will be populated with the value you provided.

Comment: Thanks. I figured there was an easy way and just couldn't see it.

Comment: Is there a way to do this using the SurveyMonkey's embedded website collector?